# UICollection View is not reloading while Navigating back?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to reload the collection view while navigating back to that particular view.

I tried implementing all the following things but its not working

1.calling self.collectionView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear()

2.calling self.collectionView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear()

3. even i tried calling viewDidLoad() in viewDidAppear but yet it is not working.

And checked the other same type of questions  but it is not working...
the only way it works is by performing segue action but I dont think so it is efficent can anyone suggest me any idea??

```
enter code here class RoomDeviceListVC: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ,segueAction{

let functions = DataFunctionalities()
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!
var horizontalBarLeadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
static var isVisible : Bool?
static var CollectionViewSection : Int!

static var reloadFlag : Int!

static var delegates : CollectionViewRotation? = nil

var uiFunctions  = UIFunctions()
var selectedIndex =  IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
var constant : CGFloat?
let headerView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    uiFunctions.setViewBackground(view: self.view)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    setupHeader()
    setupConstraints()
    setupHorizontalBar()
    collectionView2.clipsToBounds = true
    RoomDeviceListVC.CollectionViewSection = selectedIndex.section
    BottomViewRoomCell.delegates = self


}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
   //  self.collectionView2.reloadData() 

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.collectionView2.reloadData()
    RoomDeviceListVC.isVisible = true

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       RoomDeviceListVC.isVisible = false
}

func setupHorizontalBar(){
    let horizontalBar = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(horizontalBar)
    horizontalBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    horizontalBar.backgroundColor = .white
    horizontalBarLeadingConstraint = horizontalBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView2.leadingAnchor)
    horizontalBarLeadingConstraint?.isActive = true
    horizontalBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: horizontalBar, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: collectionView1, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 1).isActive =  true
    horizontalBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView2.topAnchor).isActive = true

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let menuName = ["Rooms" , "DeviceList"]
    let color :[UIColor] = [.green , .blue]


    if collectionView == collectionView1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuBarCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuBarCell
        cell.menuLabel.text = menuName[indexPath.section]
        cell.menuLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView1.selectItem(at: self.selectedIndex, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        }
        return cell

    }
    else {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BottomViewRoomCell", for: indexPath) as! BottomViewRoomCell
            cell.backgroundColor  = .clear
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 9
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BottomViewDeviceCell", for: indexPath) as! BottomViewDeviceCell
            cell.backgroundColor  = .clear
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 9
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
            return cell
        }
    }

}


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

    if collectionView  == collectionView1{
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2, height: collectionView1.frame.height)
    }
    else{
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: collectionView2.frame.height)
    }

}
```

Comment: add code with this explanation.

Comment: Are you saying that viewDidAppear() and viewWillAppear() are not getting called on the view controller at all when you navigate back by either dismissing a view controller or popping it? If this is the case then your issue must be far greater then collection view not reloading. Ensure these methods are called, ensure these are on the view controller (not a view), ensure these are on correct view controller, ensure these are plain view controllers and a custom implementation of embedded view controller.

Comment: Do your DidAppear method get called but collection View not reloading data ?

Comment: @MaticOblak   the viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear are getting called but the collection view is not reloading and i am popping it for navigating back.

Comment: @Vardan yeah the same!!

Comment: did you refresh your array of datasource ?

Comment: @KKRocks can you explain me clearly?

Comment: if you make some changes in your array then it will be effect with reloading method . if your array similar as before then it will not effect  with reloading.

Comment: how are you identifying if collection view is reloading or not? Did you add a breakpoint?

Comment: @Priyal Yeah I checked by using breakpoint in cellForItemAtIndexpath " it breaks when i load for 1st time but it does not break when I navigate back.

Comment: @KKRocks yeah the UI of the cells changes...

Comment: can you add that code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use UINavigationControllerDelegate to handle this situation.

add UINavigationControllerDelegate, sign self to the delegate of your collectionView's navigationController, and then put your personal function inside  "willShow/didShow" delegate method. your personal function will be called when you pop back to the collectionView.

some method about cell display is not shown

```
class HomeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    private let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

    //  sign navigationController's delegate to collectionViewController itself.
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    // push view controller when cell is selected
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = CustomViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    //  call your personal function when this collection view controller shows back
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            print("will show self")
        }
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            print("did show self")
        }
    }
}
```